# how to generate PDF from HTML in ionic app

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I would like to generate a PDF from a HTML page, I'm using `CORDOVA.PDF.GENERATOR` plugin. It generates the PDF but without style, I want the generated PDF with the same style as the HTML page .

I need to tell the plugin to style the page with the same styling. How can I do that?

Heading

```
let options = {
  documentSize: 'A4',
  type: 'share',
  fileName: 'myFile.pdf'
};
cordova.plugins.pdf.fromData(page[0].innerHTML, options)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var payload = _.template(' <head><link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=css_file%>">
   </head><body> <h1> Hello World </h1></body>')

    cordova.plugins.pdf.fromData((payload({css_file: cssFile}),opts)
```